# Loading images after viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, image, viewdidload

I have a view that loads over 100 images onto the screen during viewDidLoad like so:

```
cover = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:currentQuestion.image]];
cover.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentQuestion.image ofType:@"jpg"]];
cover.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cover.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
cover.frame = CGRectMake(30, (current*70), 100, 100);
[scrollView2 addSubview:cover];
```

This is taking a bit of time to load (5+ seconds) and I remember learning that you should only load what you need on the screen so I would prefer to load the first 10 images, allow the view to load, and then add the remaining images in some other function since they are initially off-screen until the user scrolls down. Where is the best place to do this?  Do I just call another function in viewDidLoad like [self loadTheRest]; or [self performSelector:@selector(loadTheRest) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f]; ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the UIScrollViewDelegate's `scrollViewDidScroll:` method such that when a user scrolls to a new location, you load the images that would be visible.

See the [UIScrollViewDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property (nonatomic,retain)  IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;
}
```